# spring mvc generic controllers and services

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

I am developing  a small RESTful application using Spring MVC and I want to implement the generic CRUD in generic controllers, services and maybe entities. I have an entity `Person` and 2 entities which inherit the fields from this entity (e.g. `Person1` and `Person2`).

What would be the best way to do it?

I saw an example where all controllers were final. Is it a bad practice to have generic controllers? What about services? How do I make a generic entity?

Answer (score 2):

I already developed something like this making generic Controller abstract one with abstract method

```
protected abstract RestService<T, ID> getService();
```

and other controller have to extends this controller and implement this method also I did the same for service with abstract method

```
protected abstract PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> getRepo();
```

to get repository to use it inside abstract service, the point you have to take care about that these abstract classes do not have @Controller or @Service, also in the sub class of Controller you have to specify your root path as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerRestController extends RestController<Customer, Long> {
```

and in abstract controller you have to use relative paths like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> update(@PathVariable ID id,
    @RequestBody T t) {
```

if you are interested in this solution I can share source code with you

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think its bad practice to have a controller not be final.  In fact, I have never written a Spring MVC controller that was final, although I could see the appeal of doing it.

As for a "generic" controller, there is nothing preventing you from creating a base-class Controller.  The Controller is just a POJO, so it would be pretty straight-forward.

Better yet, if you want to get the most bang for your buck, why not use Spring Roo?  Its all Spring MVC underneath, generates your boiler-plate code, and when you are done using it to farm out all the grunt work of creating your site, you can simply push all the roo-generated code into your own and toss it aside if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using Spring ROO, it looks really nice at beginning, but I didn't like the combination of jspx + dojo and the aspects were quite annoying too. I ended up dropping it and creating the entities  myself.

Comment: I don't like Dojo either, and I usually replace it with jQuery when I use Roo for a project.  I mostly use Roo for generating the boiler plate code for entities and basic controllers and getting Spring Security setup.  I usually do not use it to scaffold my Entities.